# Removing border on last menu Item

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

How can I remove the border from last menu item?

I tried,

```
.elementor-1785 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8e7245e 
.elementor-nav-menu .menu-item a:last-child {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #f0f0ed;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    border-color: #0274be;
}
```

but no luck. my site is https://******.dk. (url removed)

I'm using elementor plugin, & also added a custom class "noborder" on the last menu item 
[image]

Comment: If we are doing thing `PATCH` way, force border none to last element. [Look](https://imgur.com/bG3Xf1A)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. PATCH way is ok, I tried this, no luck.
.noborder.elementor-1785 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8e7245e .elementor-nav-menu .menu-item a {
    border: none;
 
  
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 .menu-item:last-child a{
     border-right: none;
 }
```

instead of

```
 .menu-item a:last-child
```

You are looking for the last child `li` not the last child `a`

Answer (score 1):

```
a:last-child {
   border: none;
}
```

We don't need border as the just last item will cover the border for us.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :last-child selector.

You will get a full description and tested way here , so that next time no worry anymore :)

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp